# JavaScript get portion of a page URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, console

Is there a way using HTML css and JavaScript that I can find the URL of a webpage after the first 10 characters. For example, if the URL is random.com/abc the program would only get the /abc part of the URl and log it in the console. How can this be done?

Comment: `(new URL('http://www.example.com/abc/123')).pathname`

Comment: Where is the URL? The webpage, a link, plain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get this done, using **window.location.href**.

Example output:

```
window.location.href: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69409934/javascript-get-portion-of-a-page-url'
```

You can split this string now, and get desired part:

```js
window.location.href.split('/')
```

Output:

```
0: "https:"
1: ""
2: "stackoverflow.com"
3: "questions"
4: "69409934"
5: "javascript-get-portion-of-a-page-url"
length: 6
```

Now log this into console:

```js
console.log(window.location.href.split('/')[3])
```

Your result:

```
'questions'
```

Comment: split() is a bad choice when it is built in....

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the pathname from the window location object.

```
window.location.pathname
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location.href` along with `substring()` to select a range of characters or characters after a particular index.

```js
window.location.href.substring(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the path, use the pathName.

```
console.log(window.location.pathname);
console.log((new URL('http://www.example.com/abc/123')).pathname);
```

There is no reason to split and use indexes.